# what is exclude regexp pattern in vim

Tags: vim

I want to match something but exclude `\t

in ruby :  `[^\t]`  which mean `match anything but`\t`

what is it's equivalence in vim ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In vim's syntax, you usually have to escape those brackets.  But there's a switch you can use at the beginning of your regex, `\v`, which turns on "very magic" handling so you don't.

It's bad for compatibility to change the default regex syntax, but I prefer not to have to type backslashes all the time.  I have these in my .vimrc, which automatically inserts the very-magic switch for me.

```
" set the "very magic" option in common searches
nnoremap / /\v
vnoremap / /\v
cnoremap s/ s/\v
```

See `:help \v` for more examples.

Comment: Not in this case, you don’t need to escape collections (unless you have set `'nomagic'` option: one of the options setting which will likely to break some scripts, but is applicable only for cmdline searches (`/`, `?`, `:/`, `:?`, `:g//`, `:s///`, but not for `:vimgrep`, `:syntax` and all functions that use regular expressions except `search()`). Syntax looks like if it was derived from POSIX BRE.